# Maven: why does it contain a seemingly broken schemaLocation?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

In every pom.xml I've seen, `xsi:schemaLocation` is specified like this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
```

Example: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html.

The second URL is a valid XSD. What is the purpose of the first URL? http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 returns a "page not found" error.

Is there another purpose to this seemingly broken URL?

Comment: Actually, it is not a URL, but rather a URI.  I don't know why it is there, but switching in the `maven-4.0.0.xsd` file results in an error, despite that it contains all the definitions for the usual Maven tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This attribute has two values, separated by a space. The first value is the namespace to use. The second value is the location of the XML schema to use for that namespace.
Which means the first part is not a real URI and can not be accessed, cause it's the namespace within the XSD and the second one is the XSD definition which can be used to check the xml file.

So this means in result there is no `broken schema`.  It is correct.

Comment: Good explanation.  The maven project should put this on their website, preferably at http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 !